# How to save objects in GridFS without taking them from a file?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, gridfs

I'm working in a Spring Boot api that can receive very large objects and try to save it in a MongoDB database. Because of this the program sometimes throws me the next error:

```
org.bson.BsonMaximumSizeExceededException: Payload document size is larger than maximum of 16793600.
```

I'd read that MongoDB only permits objects of size below 16MB, this is very inconvenient for my system because an object can easily surpass this gap. To solve this I had read about GridFS, technology that allows to surpass the 16MB files gap.

Now I'm trying to implement GridFS in my system but I only had seen examples using files to save in the database, something like this:

```
gridFsOperations.store(new FileInputStream("/Users/myuser/Desktop/text.txt"), "myText.txt", "text/plain", metaData);
```

But I want to do is not to take the data from a file, but to the api to receive a object and save it, something like this:

```
@PostMapping
    public String save(@RequestBody Object object){
        DBObject metaData = new BasicDBObject();
        metaData.put("type", "data");
        gridFsOperations.store(object, metaData);
        return "Stored successfully...";
    }
```

Is it a posible way to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Get an `InputStream` from the request and pass it to a `GridFSBucket`.  Here's a rough example:

In your controller:

```java
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request)
{
  Iterator<String> iterator = request.getFilenames();
  String filename = iterator.next();

  MultipartFile mf = request.getFile(filename);

  // I always have a service layer between controller and repository but for purposes of this example...
  myDao.uploadFile(filename, mf.getInputStream());
}
```

In your DAO/repository:

```java
private GridFSBucket bucket;

@Autowired
void setMongoDatabase(MongoDatabase db)
{
  bucket = GridFSBuckets.create(db);
}

public ObjectId uploadFile(String filename, InputStream is)
{
  Document metadata = new Document("type", "data");
  GridFSUploadOptions opts = new GridFSUploadOptions().metadata(metadata);

  ObjectId oid  = bucket.uploadFromStream(filename, is, opts);

  try
  {
     is.close();
  }
  catch (IOException ioe)
  {
    throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
  }
  
  return oid;
}
```

I paraphrased this from existing code so it may not be perfect but will be good enough to point you in the right direction.